# Smoker Ideas, something between Ribs and a Brisket

Tags: meat, smoking

Got my smoker going and the food is turning out descent.. smoked ribs and a beer can chicken quite well so far. I'm thinking of trying a brisket, but that seems intimidating with my limited smoker skillset/experience.

What's a good intermediate meat to experiment with between ribs and a brisket?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want beef, try smoking chuck roasts ("chuckies"). If you want pork, try making pulled pork from pork shoulder. Both will produce nice results, but take less time than brisket.

Comment: Agreed on pork shoulder - pretty forgiving.

Comment: Awesome idea, I think pork shoulder it is! Fantastic.